# How to disable AWS-managed CMK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I found that when I remove all of my AWS Service but the billing spend 1.02$ a month for KMS. I figure out that it was using KMS. When I going to KMS default key. It has many key (https://ap-southeast-1.console.aws.amazon.com/kms/home?region=ap-southeast-1#/kms/defaultKeys). So I want to schedule delete or disable. But it has not permission although I was attracted policy which has `kms:Delete*,` or `kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion`.
AWS-managed CMK is something like `aws/lambda`, `aws/sns`, `aws/s3`.

AWS documentation say that AWS-managed key can't be delete or disable. But how to fix it when I not using AWS KMS default-key (**not** `Customer managed keys`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I remove AWS-managed keys

You can't, because well, they are AWS-managed, not yours.

But you are [not charged](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/pricing/) for AWS-managed keys.

> You are **not charged** for the following: Creation and storage of AWS managed CMKs.

So you must have your own  customer managed key that you are charged for. Maybe in different region then you are checking.